# How to extract data from pandas dataframe with multiple values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask-dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing data and a python list which contains ids. I want to extract data from the pandas dataframe which matches with the values of list.

`ids =  ['SW00003062', 'SW00003063', 'SW00003067', 'SW00003072']`
Dataframe is this:

[image: Pandas dataframe]

Comment: use .loc, `df.loc[ids]`

Comment: Could you provide your data as a pd.Dataframe so we can test our solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin`

```py
out = df[df['id'].isin(ids)]
```